# Software Center requires libkonq5-templates package

Tags: 12.10, software-center

Whenever I open software center it crashes with below error. I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

```
E: The package libkonq5-templates needs to be reinstalled
```

But I can't find an archive for it.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall the package, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libkonq5-templates
```